# How to adjust entry fields to have different width based on field value in Craft CMS 4

Tags: craft4

I have created a entrytype where there are multiple sets of fields. One for each of 4 different languages.

In the entrytype i have selected a field of checkboxes and added conditional logic for which language to display when creating/editing an entry.

Each of the fields are set to 50% width. This makes it the same fields for different languages appear side-by-side when 2 languages are selected at the same time. Nice!

However, when only 1 language is selected, the width og 50% makes the fields appear side by side only for that language, which makes everything messy.

I want to add some logic that makes it so that when only 1 language are selected the width of all the fields become 100%.

Whats the best and easiest way to accomplish this? So far I have done everything using only standard Craft functionality.

I have tried adding a UI Element Template. But I dont seem to be able to get the values from the different fields. Am I on the right track here?

Any help would be much appreciated.